# Maximum number of elements in an array vs. maximum indexer value

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-4.5, maxlength

today I started wondering about something in the MSDN.
[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) demonstrates, how one can increase the memory allocatable by an array under .NET 4.5 and x64. This is a nice feature, but something in the description provided by Microsoft baffeles me.

Under the section "Remarks" they say, that:

> The maximum index in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and 2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for other types.

Since I mainly have `int[]` or `double[]` the latter number is relevant for my *indexing*. I can create an array with `int[] TestArray = new int[2146435071]`, which is fine. However, under the same section Microsoft states:

> The maximum number of elements in an array is UInt32.MaxValue.

Which is (according to the MSDN):

> The value of this constant is 4,294,967,295; that is, hexadecimal 0xFFFFFFFF.

Now. If I get that right, I can have an array with up to 4,294,967,295 elements (for example `ints`) but due to the array being indexed by an `int` and not an `uint` I am not able to access the "upper" half of my data?

This confuses me a lot, sice it seems I am missing something essential here.

I hope you can enlighten me

Kind Regards

EDIT:

I understand that I can create multi-dimensional arrays, but an array of length 2e9 an width 2 seems a bit stupid. Aren't multi-dimensional arrays mapped to one-dimensional ones anyway?

Comment: I assume that the "maximum number of elements" is higher because it allows for multi-dimensional arrays. `new byte[4000000000]` would not be allowed, but `new byte[4000,1000000]` would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The maximum index **in any single dimension** is 2,147,483,591

Remember that arrays can have multiple dimensions, so you *could* have a 2-D array that has up to 4,294,967,295 items, but *each dimension* can have a max length of 2,147,483,591.

So you can have a 2,147,483,591 X 2 array, but not a 1,000,000 X 1,000,000 array.

Comment: But I always thought, multi-dimensional arrays are mapped to one-dimensional ones?

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk No - they are not.

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk They're stored in one sequential block of memory.  That's not quite the same thing.

Comment: At least in C they were, weren't they?

Comment: @lhiapgpeonk That's because C doesn't have _real_ indexers, but just translates that pointer math (which is why you have a horde of buffer overrun security holes), but that can't be done in C# without `unsafe` code.  Lots of things _can_ be done in C that _shouldn't_ be done...

Comment: Well I'm fiddelling with something converted from C which uses lots of matrices and vectors. In C my arrays were defined via `malloc`, and I suppose they had no limit in size (except what x64 dictated them)

Comment: Porting code from C to C# is not trivial (particularly array/pointer code) - C# is not an _extension_ of C# - it's a _completely new language and framework_.